# Add some lines in vim

Tags: functions

```
!sed -i "N;4i\xxxxxxxx" % 
!sed -i "N;10a\yyyyyyyy" %
```

Add a line containing  `xxxxxxx` before the 4-th line,and add a line containing  `yyyyyyyy` after the 10-th line?

How to write a function to add a line containing  `xxxxxxx` before the m-th line,and add a line containing  `yyyyyyyy` after the n-th line with vimscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`:h append()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#append%28%29):

> ```
> append({lnum}, {expr})                    *append()*
>       When {expr} is a |List|: Append each item of the |List| as a
>       text line below line {lnum} in the current buffer.
>       Otherwise append {expr} as one text line below line {lnum} in
>       the current buffer.
> ```

So you can use this to add a line after the 10th line:

```
:call append(10, "yyyyyyy")
```

And to add a line before the 4th one:

```
:call append(3, "xxxxxx")
```

You may also want to read [`:h :put`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3aput)